# Removal of the tag [gst] as there is [gstreamer] already

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There are [gst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gst) and [gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gstreamer) tags and they seem to mean the same thing.

Explanation of [gst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gst):

> Questions related to GStreamer(also known as Gst), a leading open source multimedia framework, powering everything from linux servers and linux desktop systems to a host of embedded devices.

And the one of [gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gstreamer):

> GStreamer is a versatile open-source multimedia framework.

I've been following GStreamer's society for a while and I haven't noticed any common usage of [gst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gst) as a nickname for GStreamer, it's rather a common prefix used in its API. Currently, there are questions that are tagged with the [former](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gst), the [latter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gstreamer), or [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gst%20gstreamer). Should we get rid of [gst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gst)?

Comment: why not make them synonyms?

Comment: [tag:gst]: 130 questions. [tag:gstreamer]: 1705 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gst) is merged into and is now a syn. of [gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gstreamer). The tag excerpt has also been copied across.